# Failed in changing textbox value using if-else clause

Tags: html

I have already added a button with ID = "ShowAll" and i would like to execute a function to change the textbox and then remove the markers. When i click the button in the first time and the icon is successfully changed and the markers are successfully added to Google Maps. However, when i clicked the button again. The button is not changed to the original value and the code is not executed as expected. Can anyone help me to take a look on the coding. Many Thanks.

```
  var ShowAll=function() {
     if (document.getElementById("ShowAll").value = "Show All Trig Station") {
        document.getElementById("ShowAll").value="Hide All Trig Station";
        //ShowAll.value = "Hide All Trig Station";
        var URL2="Show_all_trig.php";
        $.ajax({
            url: URL2,
            // data: $('#sendForm').serialize(),
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data){
                $.each(data, function(i, item) {
                     station_num = item.station_num; 
                     trig_name = item.trig_name;
                     loc_lat = item.loc_lat;
                     loc_long = item.loc_long;
                     loc = new google.maps.LatLng(loc_lat, loc_long);   
                     var trigicon = 'images/Start2.png';
                     marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                     map: map,
                     position: loc,
                     icon: trigicon,
                     title: trig_name
                     })
                     markersArray.push(marker)
                     //html = "<b>Trig. Station Name: </b>" + trig_name + "<br/> <b>Station Number: </b>" + station_num + "<br/> <a target='_blank' href= 'summarysheet/"+ station_num +".pdf'>Trig. Station Summary</a>";
                     html = "<b>Trig. Station Name: </b>" + trig_name + "<br/> <b>Station Number: </b>" + station_num + "<br/> <a target='_blank' href= 'http://www.geodetic.gov.hk/summarysheet/"+ station_num +".pdf'>Trig. Station Summary</a>";
                     (function(temp_html,temp_map,temp_marker) {
                        google.maps.event.addListener(temp_marker, 'click', function() {
                        infoWindow.setContent(temp_html);
                        infoWindow.open(temp_map, temp_marker);
                        });
                        }(html,map,marker));
                }); 
            },

            error:function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){ 
                alert(xhr.status); 
                alert(thrownError); 
             }

        }); 
     } else {
        document.getElementById("ShowAll").value="Show All Trig Station";
        if (markersArray) {
            for (i in markersArray) {
                markersArray[i].setMap(null);
            }
        }
    }
};

   <table>
<h4>Building Name, Facilities Name and Address Search</h4>
<tr>
    <td><input type="text" size="40" id="address" value="Find building, facilities, address..." onclick="if(this.value=='Find building, facilities, address...'){this.value=''}" onblur="if(this.value==''){this.value='Find building, facilities, address...'}"></td>
    <td><input type="button" value="Geocode" onclick="codeAddress()"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Too much code. Be Specific.

Comment: On line 2 you're using `=` when you should use `===`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have made mistake here

```
if (document.getElementById("ShowAll").value = "Show All Trig Station") {
```

check the **=** symbol .. :)